# SELECT Manager of the branch with the longest serving employee

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL and am trying to create a query. I have the following table

**Employee_Branch**

```
  Employee_ID   Branch_ID      Role     Start_Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  100            10            Manager     12/9/2016
  200            20            Manager     12/9/2016
  300            10            Cashier     1/31/2018
  400            10            Cashier     1/31/2018
  500            20            Janitor     1/31/2018
  600            10            Cashier     1/31/2019
```

From this table, I want to be able to view the managers of branches with the longest serving employee (the same value as the minimum **Start_Date** value). Managers themselves are excluded from counting as the longest serving employee. There can be multiple managers per branch

From the data shown above, the needed result is

**Result I Need**

```
  Employee_ID   Branch_ID      Role      
----------------------------------------
100                10          Manager
200                20          Manager
```

Because there are two branches which contain the oldest **Start_Date** value, the managers for both branches are outputted.

If the data changed to

```
  Employee_ID   Branch_ID      Role     Start_Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  100            10            Manager     12/9/2016
  200            20            Manager     12/9/2016
  300            10            Cashier     1/31/2018
  400            10            Cashier     1/31/2018
  500            20            Janitor     1/31/2019
  600            10            Cashier     1/31/2019
```

The output would result in

```
  Employee_ID   Branch_ID      Role      
----------------------------------------
100                10          Manager
```

Because the minimum **Start_Date** is only found in branch 10, all managers assigned to branch 10 are outputted. In this case, there is only 1 manager assigned to branch 10.

**What I Have Tried**

I attempted to implement the following query as a sub query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee_Branch.Branch_ID, Min(Employee_Branch.Start_Date) AS MinOfStart_Date
FROM Employee_Branch
WHERE Employee_Branch.Role <> "Manager"
GROUP BY (Employee_Branch.Branch_ID);
```

However, this resulted in outputting the minimum **Start_Date** for each branch as opposed to all branches that contain the minimum **Start_Date**.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4afe8e/1

Comment: @Nick This works perfectly. However, I get a syntax error when implementing it as a query in Microsoft Access.

Comment: You tagged your question MySQL so that's what I've given you an answer for... I don't have access to an access machine so can't help with the translation sorry

Comment: Managed to get it working. It was simply a matter of changing the != to <>

Comment: Cool - I'm glad it was easy